# Cannot open folders from wi-fi network [20.04.2 LTS]

Tags: mac, file-sharing, lan

I have a Ubuntu laptop in my wi-fi network and I have turned on Sharing of "Documents" and "Downloads" folders.

When I go to the "Network" option in "Finder", it shows up the Ubuntu laptop and I can open it and can see that "Documents" and "Downloads" folders are there.

But the problem occurs when I try to open any of those folders. It shows me the following alert.

> The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “Downloads” can’t be found.

I have enabled all the necessary permissions in Ubuntu.

Please help me.

Checkout this question on Apple Site: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252393605

Image #1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsSTR.png

Image #2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V97dN.png

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it? It is possible the version affects the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue by enabling "Guest access" on Ubuntu.